# Turing's Craft exercise stumped me... seems too easy

Tags: c++

"Write a for loop that prints the integers 1 through 40, separated by spaces or new lines. You may use only one variable, count which has already been declared as an integer."

So I use...

```
for(count = 1; count <= 40; count++)
{
    cout << " " << count;
}
```

but they are using stdio.h as the only header and cout is not recognized. It hints that the output format should be (" ",count), but I can't figure out what print function to use. stdio.h can use fprintf or fwrite, but I don't have enough parameters for either function. Any ideas?

Comment: I suspect that's suppose to be for C, and you'd use `printf`. (Though you can use `<cstdio>` in C++ and `std::printf`.) In any case, you might want one of our [recommended C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I would say "separated" means that you shouldn't have a leading space.  There's a question here on stackoverflow about the best way to do that.

Comment: Also, cout is a variable too, and the use of the variables other than "count" is prohibited by the exercise. I think that 'printf' is the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf():

```
int count;
for (count=1; count<=40; count++)
{
    printf("%d ", count);
}
```

more on that here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: yeaaa count was already declared but I was unaware of printf.... thought it was fprintf... but I now notice the printf function on the cplusplus.com reference page... was the %d whitespace?

Comment: fprintf will print the numbers to a file, and it also takes an extra argument. You can find that on cplusplus.com

Comment: The %d indicates to the function that you want an integer value, so for example printf("%d, %d", 5, 10); would produce the output "5, 10"

Comment: What would result in the whitespace it requires... as /n isnt accepted.

Comment: simply put a space right after %d. Anything you put there that isn't right after the % is written exactly as is. So the above code will generate the whitespace you need because there's a space right after the %d.

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat on the last item so it doesn't have the trailing space/newline/comma etc...

```
int count;
for( count = 1; count <= 39; count++ )
{
    printf( "%d ", count );
}
printf( "%d\n", ++count );
```

If this is homework, ignore my answer and figure it out for yourself! :)

Answer (score -1):

You are thinking too much try this.

```
for (count = 1; count <= 40; count++)
{
    cout << count << endl;
}
```